# Bootstrap Nav-Bar centered but DIV higher then content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

after 1 hour of try and error and searching for problems like this, i try to get an answer here.

I want to include a bootstrap Nav-Bar into a Div.
I centered the Nav-Bar, but now my Div is higher then the content. This problem is only available when the Nav-Bar is centered. If i let if float left, the space below the Nav-Bar isnt there...

[Screenshot (i want to remove the red-striped part)](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wwx95vf5a97pbgq/Unbenannt.png?dl=0)

here my Code:

[Code](http://bit.ly/1BgEkWh)

Comment: I don't see how this involved jQuery or JavaScript.

Comment: i just posted the necessary Part of my Html :) Its just a css problem

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vOJrmO .. Can you elaborate on what you're trying to do here in the context of the example? It contains all of the code you have here.

Comment: Have you try to add `margin: 0;` in `ul` and remove the `line-height` in `#header`?

Comment: the gap is smaller, but its still the same problem

Answer (score 1):

a `margin-bottom:0;` will do the trick if added to `navbar`

```
.navbar {
    margin-bottom:0;
 }
```

### [This is a bootstrap example with both navbar and jumbotron](http://www.bootply.com/77244)

Comment: i have no .navbar class here

Comment: use class nav instead of navbar. it should work too.

Comment: No, didnt work :( its 100% a problem with with the text-align becuase its working when i float:left the ul

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#header {        
    color: white;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #222222;
    font-weight: 100;   
    margin: auto;
    padding: 30px 0;
    text-align: center; 
    font-size: 1.2em;
}
```

Comment: This looks much better, but the text is still not 100% vertical-centered